# How do I check two different conditions for one column in an INSERT INTO SELECT block?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

database noob so please bear with me. Writing in Oracle MySql.

I have a block of code which notably is meant to add rows to DWCUST but change invalid gender values coming from a2custbris to valid ones by comparing them to the genderspelling table. I wrote the select code in the brackets to do this and it works. However, certain gender values are null in a2custbris, I want these to be written as 'U' in DWCUST. So how can I do both?

Here's the code:

```sql
INSERT INTO DWCUST (DWCUSTID, DWSOURCEIDBRIS, DWSOURCEIDMELB, FIRSTNAME, SURNAME, GENDER, PHONE, POSTCODE, CITY, STATE, CUSTCATNAME)
SELECT dwcustSeq.nextval, cb.custid, Null, cb.fname, cb.sname, (select trim(gs.NEW_VALUE) FROM genderspelling gs WHERE upper(gs.INVALID_VALUE) = upper(cb.GENDER)), cb.phone, cb.postcode, cb.city, cb.state, cc.custcatname
FROM a2custbris cb
NATURAL JOIN a2custcategory cc
WHERE cb.rowid IN (SELECT source_rowid FROM A2ERROREVENT where filterid = 7);
```

Any help is creating appreciated!

Comment: On a side note: Natural joins are very prone to errors (because adding a column to a table later may lead to strange results of existing queries). So, better make it a habit to never use them. Also, don't ever store ROWIDs in order to use them later. They can change. Only work with ROWIDs inside the same transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
INSERT INTO DWCUST (DWCUSTID, DWSOURCEIDBRIS, DWSOURCEIDMELB, FIRSTNAME, SURNAME,
                    GENDER, PHONE, POSTCODE, CITY, STATE, CUSTCATNAME)
SELECT
  dwcustSeq.nextval, cb.custid, Null, cb.fname, cb.sname, 
  CASE WHEN cb.gender IS NULL THEN 'U' 
       ELSE (select trim(gs.NEW_VALUE) FROM genderspelling gs
             WHERE upper(gs.INVALID_VALUE) = upper(cb.GENDER))
  END,
  cb.phone, cb.postcode, cb.city, cb.state, cc.custcatname
FROM a2custbris cb
NATURAL JOIN a2custcategory cc
WHERE cb.rowid IN (SELECT source_rowid FROM A2ERROREVENT where filterid = 7);
```

If you want `'U'` for every value that has no match in `genderspelling`, then use `COALESCE` instead:

```
INSERT INTO DWCUST (DWCUSTID, DWSOURCEIDBRIS, DWSOURCEIDMELB, FIRSTNAME, SURNAME,
                    GENDER, PHONE, POSTCODE, CITY, STATE, CUSTCATNAME)
SELECT
  dwcustSeq.nextval, cb.custid, Null, cb.fname, cb.sname, 
  COALESCE(
    (select trim(gs.NEW_VALUE) FROM genderspelling gs
     WHERE upper(gs.INVALID_VALUE) = upper(cb.GENDER))
  , 'U'),
  cb.phone, cb.postcode, cb.city, cb.state, cc.custcatname
FROM a2custbris cb
NATURAL JOIN a2custcategory cc
WHERE cb.rowid IN (SELECT source_rowid FROM A2ERROREVENT where filterid = 7);
```

Comment: Perfect for what I asked, thank you! But I misspoke, rather than checking for null, I want to check whether cb.gender matches any of the values in genderspelling (because this will include both null values and values that aren't null but don't match anything in genderspelling), how can I adjust your code to do this check instead before the else?

If it helps, genderspelling has two columns, new_value and invalid_value

Comment: Okay, you want 'U' when your subquery returns null. I've updated my answer accordingly.